# Should the concentrations in weight % of the components of a solution always add up to 100%?

Tags: aqueous-solution, concentration

There's a paper with this statement of a alkaline solution:

> Nanostructured CuO films were formed by immersing the cleaned tabs into a hot $(\pu{96 \pm 3 ^\circ C})$ alkaline solution composed of $\ce{NaClO2}$, $\ce{NaOH}$, $\ce{Na3PO4 * 12 H2O}$, and DI water $(\pu{3.75 : 5 : 10 : 100 wt.\%})$.

I have looked online and read that normally the wt.% should add up to 100%. However, this statement says that DI water is at 100%. Is there something I am missing?

paper in context - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2975.pdf

Comment: These numbers separated with a colon look like a ratio to me, not the absolute values.

Comment: So they are just weight ratios, and the total at 100% would just be 118.75? Thus wt% of the 1st compound would just be 3.75/118.75?

Comment: $3.75/118.75 \cdot 100\%$, to be precise. That's how I see it.

Comment: To be 100% sure you can contact the authors – this is just my opinion and shouldn't be taken for granted.

Comment: Yup, I have done that as well and am waiting on their reply :)

Comment: Please add the citation to the paper so that it can be seen in context.

Comment: Could be the wrong /misuse of % m/V as well. Water is about 100 because they think 100 g gives 100 ml. There are plenty of errors like that even if might not be the current case, is better to be aware of the misuse of notation created for very diluted aqueous solutions